# Unhandled Promise Rejection AOT(Ahead Of Time) Angular 2

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-aot

I have an small Angular 2 app that fetches the data from ASP.net MVC Web API. Using Authentication. I am trying to use Ahead Of Time compiler in Angular 2. I am running the following command

> node_modules \ .bin\ngc -p src

but i am getting following error

> (node:13640) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Right-hand side of
>   'instanceof' is not an object (node:13640) DeprecationWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
>   rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
>   with a non-zero exit code.

can some one tell me how to resolve it

> This is my directory structure

I have move the tsconfig.json from root to src folder as it was directed in this [link](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-ngmodule/)

[image: Directory structure]

> That's how i am using promise

**I have made services from which i return the promise like this:**

```
public get(servicename: string) {
    this.colorlog.log('get ' + servicename + " ",enmMessageType.Info);
    return this.http.get(this.ngWEBAPISettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "api/" + servicename + "/", this.ngWEBAPISettings.getConfig()).toPromise();
}
```

and consuming it in component like this

```
get() {
    var promise = this.setupServicePromise.get(this.SERVICE_NAME);

    promise.then((response: any) => {
      this.colorlog.log('in then promise ProductComponent get' + response,   enmMessageType.Data);
      this.vm.Products = response.json();
    }).catch((error: any) => {
      this.colorlog.log("Error Occurred in product", enmMessageType.Error);
    });
}
```

this is my ts.config file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your tsconfig file?

Comment: please check the question

Comment: i had this issue and i resolved it by updating my angular to lates 2.4.1, i mean angular/core, common, form, compiler, compiler-cli. try this

Comment: @MrJSingh updating the versions and after some changing it works thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @MrJSingh, did you read an article or blog or github repo issue about this? Why did you decide to upgrade to 2.4.1? It seems to work in my case, I just could not find on the net why that action resolves the issue. Thanks

Comment: @MrJSingh, don't worry, I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13204), which was reported on Angular 2.2.4 but the issue appears to have propagated to Angular 2.3. The issue relates to some incompatibility with TypeScript 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have accomplish this in following steps

**First**

I have updated the version as mentioned by  **MrJSingh**

After updateh **package.json** dependencies section become like this.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
  "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
  "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "5.0.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
},
```

**Second**

After that i have made changes to **app.module.ts** file and change **useValue** to **useFactory**

change this

```
let authService = new AuthService(new LocalStorage());
providers: [
  {provide:AuthService,useValue:authService},
  AdminAuthGuard,
  UserAuthGuard,
  SetupServicePromise,
  SetupServiceObservables
]
```

to this

```
export function authServiceFactory() {
  return new AuthService(new LocalStoragee());
}

providers: [
  {provide:AuthService,useFactory:authServiceFactory},
  AdminAuthGuard,
  UserAuthGuard,
  WebAPISettings,
  LoginService,
  SetupServicePromise,
  SetupServiceObservables
]
```

Finally command runs successfully after these two steps.

> **Note**

For Latest version use declaracions instead of providers

```
declarations: [
  {provide:AuthService,useFactory:authServiceFactory},
  AdminAuthGuard,
  UserAuthGuard,
  WebAPISettings,
  LoginService,
  SetupServicePromise,
  SetupServiceObservables
]
```

For more detail check this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#declarations)

Comment: In these weeks, angular modules don't have providers, instead they have declarations.